# RVM error with deploying Rails app via Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rvm

History:

- Read into Deploying Rails3 app to a
  Mediatemple DV server.
- Installed RVM on the server, ruby, and essential gems.
- Site works fine if I FTP it up.
- All good.

I then decided to do a proper deployment and setup for GIT/cap deploy as per "Agile Web Development with Rails".

- Attempted deploy with cap, but had errors with gems not available to the production site.
- Read around and realised I should probably go for a system wide RVM install.
- Removed all gems and RVM.
- Installed RVM system wide.
- Error on cap deploy "bash: /home/foo/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory", which makes sense - there is no .rvm/ in the home directory.
- Thinking something was hanging over from initially installing RVM to use as a user, I removed the user, deleting the home directory, and recreated the user with permissions.
- Same error on cap deploy "bash: /home/foo/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory"

The situation now is:

For foo, .bashrc contains the last line:

```
[[ -s '/usr/local/lib/rvm' ]] && source '/usr/local/lib/rvm'
```

When I issue:

```
type rvm | head -1
```

the response is "rvm is a function".

/etc/rvmrc contains

```
if [[ ! -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]; then
  umask g+w
  export rvm_selfcontained=0
  export rvm_prefix="/usr/local/"
fi
```

Running out of ideas here, and hoping for some suggestions.

Comment: Resolved. I just got rid if RVM. Works great now. I'll save RVM for my development machine...

Answer (score 78):

Next time try to add this in your capistrano:

```
set :rvm_type, :system
```

Comment: Very helpful. Alternatively you can set :rvm_type to :user if you are deploying to a server with a single-user rvm install.

Comment: @mpapis how do you know if you have a single-user rvm install or system install? I don't remember which one I did.

Comment: you can check after logging in to server and running `echo $rvm_path`

Comment: @mpapis what exactly does this command do? It says "use_sudo is set to 'false' but sudo is needed to install rvm_type: system", but im not sure of consequences of rvm_type: system

Comment: Now if I already have RVM installed in /usr/local, multiuser installation, why do I need to add this to deploy.rb for every deploy?

Comment: `/usr/local` corresponds to `:system` installation, the default changed long time ago to be `:user` installation so you need to tell the script to use `:system` - because that is your type of installation.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the connection between rvm and capistrano. When you have a moment, can you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549477/capistrano-and-managing-rvm-patch-levels-and-ruby-versions thanks

Answer (score 5):

It seems like rvm-shell is not in your rvm install directory. Run this command

```
rvm get head
```

Then you'll get it right in your rvm bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to @imonyse's comment.

the head branch of rvm might be a tad too unstable for some deploys. I know our deprecated SLES boxes have a tendency to choke on it. It might be advisable to get the most recent stable version.

```
rvm get stable
```

Also don't do this on a really old server running production code as it may have undesired consequences.